# Insight meditation

Tags: theravada

During  meditation lost connection between body  and the thoughts. Body remains silent  but thoughts stop arise that particular matter .which  are arise remain as a flow.What is this experience?

Answer (score 1):

Mind is not silent. The mind thinks that it is silent. The knowing itself is a mental activity. So if you think that the mind is silent, that is a mental activity. Meditate on it as thinking.... thinking... thinking... or knowing... knowing... knowing...

Comment: Only mental activity  is there. No connection between body and the thoughts.

Comment: Be mindful of the mental activity

Comment: When  the mindfulness  arise there is no thoughts and cittarupa  seen the only wisdom  coming.

Comment: Wisdom means non judgment has appeared.

Comment: There's knowing. Be mindful of the knowing

Comment: Actually good judgement is a big part of wisdom. You got it in reverse.

Comment: In mind  conscious  judgment  is not the wisdom.

Comment: Good judgment is wisdom. Cloudiness or vagueness in the mind is not wisdom.

Comment: No cloudy  and vauge. Brilliant light appears with the wisdom. If there is a judgment  there is a self  know.

Comment: Self is not required for good judgement